# Trying to query with EF Core 7 with class hierarchy, one-to-many and getting errors

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-7.0

I am using EF Core 7, and the following classes modeling data from the database.

- `EmpProdSupCode` with columns RecId, Code, and others

I have created another class called `ProductCode` which extends `EmpProdSuppCode` with an appropriate discriminator setup in `modelBuilder` in `OnModelCreating`.

Next I have `ProductTypes` with `Id`, `ProductCode`, `LineCode`.

I'm trying to load all the data from `ProductCode` (which extends `EmpProdSuppCode`) and include

```
ProductJdfType. I have the right .Includes to load.

var productCodes = await context.ProductCodes
                                .Select(x => x)
                                .Include(x => x.ProductJdfTypes)
                                .ToListAsync();
```

But now when I try to query to load the data, I get errors about the foreign keys.

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The relationship from 'ProductJdfType.ProductCodeValue' to 'EmployeeProductSupplierCode.ProductJdfTypes' with foreign key properties {'ProductCode' : string} cannot target the primary key {'Id' : int} because it is not compatible. Configure a principal key or a set of foreign key properties with compatible types for this relationship.'

I'm trying to tell the `modelBuilder` about the specific keys, but I can't seem to get it right. Can anyone help with this please?